# cursor blinking changed till restart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I am working on a .net windows forms control where i have used the below code to use modify the caret in my custom textbox

```
  [DllImport("User32.dll")]
     static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCaretPos(int x, int y);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
   static extern bool DestroyCaret();
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
  static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   static extern bool SetCaretBlinkTime(uint uMSeconds);

   protected override void OnGotFocus(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateCaret(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 8, 14);
        SetCaretPos(2, 1);
        ShowCaret(this.Handle);
        SetCaretBlinkTime(100);
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }
         protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        DestroyCaret();
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }
```

but i found out that once i run the project , the blinking rate of my windows cursor have changed too till i restart my windows xp (sp2) .

any suggestion on why it is happening ?

Comment: Did you read the Remarks section of [SetCaretBlinkTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcaretblinktime)?

Comment: Thanks jimi , but do u have a solution for this .

Comment: If have read the notes in the Docs, the solution is not to call `SetCaretBlinkTime()`

Comment: Thanks again jimi ,can u suggest me another way to increase the blinking time of my caret .

Comment: Jimi means, according to the description of the document, Applications should respect the setting that the user has chosen. In addition, even if you get pre_blink_time by `GetCaretBlinkTime` in `OnGotFocus` and `SetCaretBlinkTime(pre_blink_time)` in `OnLostFocus`, the issue may also occur. Then you will need to draw a caret in the control, set the timer and "blink" it by yourself.

Comment: @drake , can u please share a link of what you have suggested . I am new to c#. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To draw a caret by your self:

```
public class CueTextBox : TextBox
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetCaretPos(out POINT pt);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public UInt32 x;
        public UInt32 y;
    };
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool DestroyCaret();
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetCaretBlinkTime();
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetTimer(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr nIDEvent, uint uElapse, IntPtr lpTimerFunc);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool KillTimer(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr nIDEvent);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool InvalidateRect(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lpRect, Int32 bErase);

    private bool show = true;
    protected override void OnGotFocus(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HideCaret(this.Handle);
        IntPtr nIDEvent = new IntPtr(1);
        SetTimer(this.Handle, nIDEvent, 100, IntPtr.Zero);
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }
    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        //SetCaretBlinkTime(530);
        IntPtr nIDEvent = new IntPtr(1);
        KillTimer(this.Handle, nIDEvent);
        show = false;
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }
    protected virtual void OnTimer(EventArgs e)
    {
        InvalidateRect(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        show = !show;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        POINT pt = new POINT();
        GetCaretPos(out pt);
        SolidBrush brush;
        if (show)
        { 
            brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, pt.x, pt.y, 8, 14);
        }
    }

    const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
    const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
    const int WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008;
    const int WM_TIMER = 0x0113;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
        {
            this.OnPaint(new PaintEventArgs(Graphics.FromHwnd(m.HWnd), this.ClientRectangle));
        }
        if (m.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS)
        {
            this.OnGotFocus(new EventArgs());
        }
        if (m.Msg == WM_KILLFOCUS)
        {
            this.OnLostFocus(new EventArgs());
        }
        if (m.Msg == WM_TIMER)
        {
            this.OnTimer(new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Use [`SetTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) to set a "blinktime", and then [`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) in the `WM_TIMER` to trigger `WM_PAINT` message, then simulate the blinking caret in `OnPaint` method.